# Visual Studio 2013 Error When Debugging Every So Often

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I keep getting this error below every so often with Visual Studio 2013.  I believe it has to do with the async nature of connecting it with the browser.  Is there a reason why this is happening, a bug?

```
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
```

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Did you able to fix it?

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Did you able to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Open the debug options (menu bar -> Debug -> Options) and disable:

- "Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries (Managed only)"
- "Enable Just My Code"

(Under Debugging \ General)

Msdn: [source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/79a7b495-118d-4fd6-8b9e-be51379dfbd2/visual-studio-2012-is-stopping-on-exceptions-when-all-the-settings-tell-it-not-to?forum=visualstudiogeneral)